# VSCode R extension can't run R interactively

Tags: r, visual-studio-code

I'm using VSCode to write R(version 4.1.0) on Windows 10, also I have installed radian. It seems that each setting is on the right way, but I can only excute Rscript. The default terminal is also on cmd but not on radian.

```
"r.rpath.windows": "E:\\R\\R-4.1.0\\bin\\R.exe",
"r.alwaysUseActiveTerminal": true,
"r.rterm.windows": "E:\\Anaconda\\Scripts\\radian.exe",
"r.rterm.option": [
  "--no-site-file"
 ],
"r.bracketedPaste": true,
"r.sessionWatcher":true
```

I've been traped on this issue for a whole day. Help me please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VSCode is a language agnostic IDE, so it won't set R or Radian as default unless you set to (actually, you shouldn't do that. let cmd as default).

To open an R terminal, open the command pallet with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> or F1 and type "R: create terminal".

If yet you want to use radian as default (which, again, you shouldn't), add a Radian profile:

```
"terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {

        "Radian": {
            "path": "C:\\path\\to\\radian.exe"
}
```

Then in the terminal, next to the "+" sign, access the dropdown menu and then "select default profile".

For config suggestion, [check this out](https://datamares.netlify.app/en/post/r-vscode/).

Comment: Problem has been solved through your help. Thanks a lot：）

Comment: @ZHChain If Alberson's solution solved your problem, you should upvote it and select it as the answer. If you solved the problem yourself a different way, you should write an answer to your own question and accept that, to aid future readers who may encounter the same issue.

Comment: Add a helper comment for how to find radian.exe in Windows 11 Pro. After installing radian following its authors' Github README.md, one can enter "where.exe radian.exe" to find the path to radian.exe and fill Alberson's answer in the ""C:\\path\\to\\radian.exe.  (Of course one can also use "find" in Windows Explorer, although it may take longer to find it. I found this in a web back page, so think it may be helpful to note it here.